# Error while using getters and setters in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, getter-setter

I was trying to write a getter in kotlin.
Here is my code:

```
fun main(){
    val car=Car()
    print(car.myCar)
}

class Car {
    var myCar: String="BMW"
    get() {
        return this.myCar.toLowerCase()
    }
}
```

When I executed I got this exception: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError`

I saw in some tutorial where they use `field`.

My question is why this is giving me an exception and why and how should I use `field`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you created an infinite loop.

```
var myCar: String = "BMW"
    get() {
        return this.myCar.toLowerCase()
    }
```

is equal to

```
var myCar: String = "BMW"
    get() = this.myCar.get().toLowerCase()
```

as you can see, your "get" function is recursive. So you need to use the `field` keyword to avoid calling the `get()` method:

```
var myCar: String = "BMW"
    get() = field.toLowerCase()
```

Comment: How is it recursive? How often is it called?

Comment: when you write `this.myCar`, you call the getter. So your getter is recursive because your call it in the getter implementation.

Comment: In other words, you are doing this `fun get(): String = get().toLowerCase()`, which is an infinite loop.

Comment: @AdityaDixit Recursive means it calls _itself_.  If something calls the getter, before it converts to upper case the first thing it does is to call the getter, which (in the same way) calls the getter, which calls the getter, which…  To fix it you need to get the value of the backing fields _without_ calling the getter, which is what `field` gives you.

Comment: So you mean, when I call `this.myCar`, it'll call getter then in getter `this.myCar` is there so it'll call itself again and again?

Comment: exactly! that is what i tried to explain. Can you accept the answer please?

Comment: I had one last question, what do you exactly mean by field?

Comment: a property has 3 elements: a getter, a setter and a backing field. The backing field is the value holded in memory. You can only access it from the accessors(getter and setter) of the property, using the `field` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun main(){
    val car=Car()
    print(car.myCar)
}

class Car {
    var myCar: String="BMW"
    get() = field
}
```